# Convert ActivityGroup to Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to convert my entire project from using ActivityGroups to using Fragments.

Here is my old code :

**SettingsActivityGroup**

```
public class SettingsActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup 
{
// Keep this in a static variable to make it accessible for all the nested activities, lets them manipulate the view
public static SettingsActivityGroup group;

// Need to keep track of the history if you want the back-button to work properly, don't use this if your activities requires a lot of memory.
private ArrayList<View> history;

// Window focus changed listener
public OnActivityGroupViewChanged activityGroupViewChangedListener = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Allocate history
    this.history = new ArrayList<View>();

    // Set group
    group = this;             

    // Start root (first) activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class); // Change to the first activity of your ActivityGroup
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    ReplaceView("SettingsActivity", myIntent);
}
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity 
{
String[] settingsLabels = {"Viderestilling", "Voicemail", "Vis nummer",
          "Kø styring", "Optag samtaler", "Services" };
ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.settings);
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SettingsLV);

  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  populateListView();


}

private void populateListView()
{

      lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.settings_items, R.id.settings_item_label, settingsLabels));
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) 
        {
            // SwitchActivity(position);
        }
      });
}
```

If I want to extend ListFragment instead of Activity - What do I need to change to make sure that everything still works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Developer Guide article on [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)?  I think it very nearly describes your exact use case (an array-backed list in one fragment and the detail in another).  And do check out the complete sample implementation in [APIDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Fragment).  There's even a backward-compatible version in [API 4+ Support Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/index.html).